# Converting Subversive ProjectSets to Subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive

A few co-workers and I have been looking at branching in SVN using Eclipse. Until now, we've been using Subversive, but we haven't been able to get consistent results. Sometimes we'll get conflicts sometimes we won't, sometimes it only sees changes in half the files, etc.

I have been experimenting with Subclipse and have had consistent results that perform exactly the way we want every time. The only hold-up to switching to Subclipse is that we currently use Subversive ProjectSets to set up our workspaces.

I've read that Subversive can read ProjectsSets generated by Subclipse, but it seems the reverse isn't true. Is there a way to make ProjectSets created with Subversive available to Subclipse? Or would we have to re-create the ProjectSet with Subclipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. I did not find an automated solution but the structure seemed simple enough so I just ran some regexes over the project set generated by subversive to transform it into one of subclipse style. I had to do two things:

1. *Changing the provider ID*
   from

   ```
   <provider id="org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnnature">
   ```

   to

   ```
   <provider id="org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core.svnnature">
   ```
2. than for each project tag I had to adjust parts of the reference attribute which is a list of comma separated values. The first comma separated value was some kind of a version number I had to change from `1.0.1` to `0.9.3` and additionally I had to remove all values after the first three i.e.:

   from

   ```
   <project reference="1.0.1,https://svnroot.url/projectfolder,projectname,101067470c700010138cd5110c947ae0;https://svnroot.url/projectfolder;https://svnroot.url/projectfolder;;;;false;cc4a8bc3-49ff-40c0-b9b6-f760b69cc066;https://svnroot;;false;;;0"/>
   ```

   to

   ```
   <project reference="0.9.3,myurl/projectname,projectname"/>
   ```

My Regexes:
find: `<(.*?)".*?,(.*?,.*?),.*>`
replace: `<\1"0.9.3,\2"/>`

The working sets definition worked for me without the need to adjust something.